# Limit clients from making client.restart() call is multiuser cluster

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have created dask-ssh cluster which is shared among multiple users. We do not have resource manager yet (looking at job-queue with batch grid).

I like to limit admin to be able to restart cluster and not have users/client be able to run client.restart() at whim and interfere with other clients.

If its not possible then do you suggest to let every user create there own dask-cluster ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following config may solve your problem

```yaml
distributed:
  scheduler:
    blocked-handlers:
    - restart
```

> If its not possible then do you suggest to let every user create there own dask-cluster ?

This is also a good option.